# Two Test Methods are not working simultaneously in Watin, Gallio and MbUnit

Tags: c#, watin, automated-tests

When I am writing this piece of code it works fine

```
using System;
using WatiN.Core;
using MbUnit.Framework;
using Gallio.Framework;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using Gallio.Model;

namespace DialogHandlerTestWithWatin
{
[TestFixture]
class Program
{
    //This is WatiN - create IE instance
    public static IE ie = new IE();
    [SetUp]
    public void DoTestSetup()
    {
        IE.Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 60;
    }
    [TearDown]
    public static void TestNavigateToMedappz()
    {
        if (ie != null)
        {
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed)
            {
                Assert.Fail("Unable to navigate to the medappz application");
                ie.Close();
                ie.Dispose();
                ie = null;
            }
        }
    }


    //This funcn navigate us to the Medappz Application
    [Test]
    public static void NavigateToMedappz()
    {
        using (TestLog.BeginSection("Go to Medappz"))
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(ie);
            ie.GoTo("http://192.168.10.82/Sage/");
            ie.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
        }
        //This is NUnit - check that ie instance is not null
        Assert.IsNotNull(ie, "Error creating IE instance.");
        Assert.AreEqual("Login Page", ie.Title);

    }
```

But when I add another test method in this code as

```
    [TearDown]
    public static void TestLoginToMedappz()
    {
        if (ie != null)
        {
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed)
            {
                Assert.Fail("Unable to Login");
            }
        }
    }
    [Test]
    public static void LoginToMedappz()
    {
        using (TestLog.BeginSection("Login to Medappz"))
        {
            TextField UserName = ie.TextField(Find.ByName("txtUserName"));
            UserName.TypeText("<username>");
            TextField Password = ie.TextField(Find.ByName("txtPassword"));
            Assert.IsTrue(UserName.Exists, "UserName Textbox does not exist");
            Assert.IsTrue(Password.Exists, "Password Textbox does not exist");
            Password.TypeText("<password>");
            Button btnLogin = ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnLogin"));
            Assert.IsTrue(btnLogin.Exists, "btnLogin button does not exist");
            btnLogin.Blur();
            btnLogin.Click();
        }
    }
```

Then the test started failing, only a blank IE window opens up and after few seconds the first test method is executed but the second method doesn't gets executed.The Gallio test report says

Root 
110
Results: 2 run, 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 inconclusive, 0 skipped 
Duration: 44.042s 
Assertions: 3 
WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException: Could not find INPUT (text password textarea hidden) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' with value 'txtUserName'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the two tests in the same class?  I've never seen two teardowns in the same class.  Also, if TestNavigateToMedappz is called before LoginToMedappz then your ie variable will have already been disposed.  How about you have just one teardown, then at the start of LoginToMedappz you call NavigateToMedappz?

Comment: Doing this what you say will call Navigate to Medappz for two times...isn't it

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're trying to do...

You have two tests here.  The NavigateToMedappz test tries to navigate to your app.  The LoginToMedappz test first tries to navigate to your app, and THEN it tries to login.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MedappzTests
{
    private IE ie;

    [SetUp]
    public void DoTestSetup()
    {
        ie = new IE();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void DoTestTeardown()
    {
        if (ie != null)
        {
            ie.Close();
            ie.Dispose();
            ie = null;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void NavigateToMedappz()
    {
        //...
    }

    [Test]
    public void LoginToMedappz()
    {
        NavigateToMedappz();
        //...
        //Here I'm assuming that if you've successfully logged in then the login button should no longer exist
        Assert.IsFalse(btnLogin.Exists);
    }
}
```

HTH!